# How do I make phpcs ignore some files in PHP Storm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've set up PHP Storm to use phpcs and show me in the IDE when I've violated a style.

However, I'd like to disable this for view files -- they often contain bits of PHP mixed with HTML that don't match the style guide, and I don't care in a view file.

In the options, I see a list of excluded files in the phpcs settings, but it only has buttons to remove a file or clear the whole list, but no way to ADD files to it.

Am I missing it somewhere?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Code Sniffer (as well as Mess Detector) integration is implemented in form of an Inspection which can be configured to be ON or OFF based on *scope*. Therefore:

1. `Settings | Scopes` -- create new custom scope and include all unwanted files/folders
2. `Settings | Inspections | PHP | PHP Code Sniffer validation` -- right click on it and choose `Add Scope`
3. Now configure this inspection: turn OFF (uncheck) for that scope and leave ON for "Everywhere else" entry.

**P.S.**
PhpStorm v8 has Inspections settings screen a bit redesigned; therefore steps are tiny bit different, but still the same overall (now it's easier for user to discover "scopes" functionality).

Answer (score 6):

This has been tested for **PHPStorm 2017.***

1. Settings/Preferences | Keymap

   find **Add to PHPCS ignore list** key and add Keyboard Shortcut
   [image]
2. Go to the file, which one you want to add as ignored and use the shortcut
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

With PHPStorm 8, you can find the Code Sniffer settings panel in:

**Settings | Languages and Frameworks | PHP | Code Sniffer**

In this panel, you will find a list of ignored files.

Edit: **with PHPStorm 2016.x, this list is read only, you can't add ignore files this way.**

Comment: There's a list, but how do I add to it?

Comment: There's not way for add new ignore folder.

Answer (score 3):

Update, as of November, 2019 ... now you can completely ignore files.

> Settings > Inspections > PHP > Quality Tools > PHP Code Sniffer

then

> Check files with extensions: `Remove unnecessary like js, inc`

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the toolbar to include a button for the "Add to PHPCS ignore list" action.

1. View > Toolbar to display the toolbar if it's hidden.
2. Mouse-right on toolbar, then "Customise Menus and Toolbars".
3. Select "Main Toolbar" and add the action as a button.

Or customise the Editor Tab Popup Menu and add "Add to PHPCS ignore list" there (It'll be hidden for files already on the list).